# Bootstrap 3 nav bar menu items - fade in and out

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 and have a simple navbar as follows...

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This works fine but i would now like each menu item to fade in and out on hover. For example, on hover - change background from white to black whilst fading.

Is this possible using bootstrap transitions? Or do I need to do this independent of Bootstrap with Jquery? Any help or code suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the color and background to the anchor element on hover, just like this:

```css
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    -webkit-transition: all ease .3s;
       -moz-transition: all ease .3s;
         -o-transition: all ease .3s;
            transition: all ease .3s;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

**Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thiagobraga/6yA9h/**